# html5 video - using the progress event with dynamically loaded videos

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events

I'm having a bit of difficulty using the 'progress' event to check if a video is 100% loaded. It only seems to work in Chrome/Safari. Firefox doesn't seem to want to 'preload' a video unless I try to play it.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="control">
    <a data-video="video/transport/1.0.webm">video1</a>
    <a data-video="video/transport/2.0.webm">video2</a>
    <a data-video="video/transport/3.0.webm">video3</a>
    <a data-video="video/transport/4.0.webm">video3</a>
    <a data-video="video/transport/5.0.webm">video3</a>
</div>

<video id="video" width="960" height="500" type="video/webm" autobuffer></video>
```

Here is my js (code borrowed from [chrome html5 video buffered.end event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364313/chrome-html5-video-buffered-end-event)):

```
$(function(){

    var vid = document.getElementById('video');

    vid.addEventListener('progress', onProgress, false);

    $('#control a').click(function(){
        vid.src = $(this).attr('data-video');
        vid.load();
    });

});

function onProgress(e){

    var vid = document.getElementById('video');
    var percent = null;

    if (vid.buffered.length > 0 && vid.buffered.end && vid.duration) {
        percent = vid.buffered.end(0) / vid.duration;
    } else if (vid.bytesTotal != undefined && vid.bytesTotal > 0 && vid.bufferedBytes != undefined) {
        percent = vid.bufferedBytes / vid.bytesTotal;
    }

    if (percent !== null) {
        percent = 100 * Math.min(1, Math.max(0, percent));

        console.log(percent);
    }

}
```

Comment: autobuffer isn't an attribute for the video element, try preload instead which can be set to auto, none, or meta.

Comment: thanks for the tips - @longilong make your comment an asnwer and I will accept it. the discussion you linked help me solve my problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this discussion: [HTML5 Video - File Loading Complete Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138077/html5-video-file-loading-complete-event)

```
var videoDuration = $html5Video.attr('duration');

var updateProgressBar = function(){
 if ($html5Video.attr('readyState')) {
    var buffered = $html5Video.attr("buffered").end(0);
    var percent = 100 * buffered / videoDuration;

    //Your code here

    //If finished buffering buffering quit calling it
    if (buffered >= videoDuration) {
            clearInterval(this.watchBuffer);
    }
}
};
var watchBuffer = setInterval(updateProgressBar, 500);
```