# Wait until an HTML5 video loads

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a video tag, that I dynamically change its source as I am letting the user to choose from a number of videos from the database. The problem is that when I change the src attribute the video doesn't load even if I tell it to.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#video").attr('src', 'my_video_'+value+'.ogg');
$("#video").load();
while($("#video").readyState !== 4) {
    console.log("Video is not ready");
};
```

The code still stays in a infinite loop.

Any help?

**EDIT**:

To Ian Devlin:

```js
//add an listener on loaded metadata
v.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    console.log("Loaded the video's data!");
    console.log("Video Source: "+ $('#video').attr('src'));
    console.log("Video Duration: "+ $('#video').duration);
}, false);
```

Ok this is the code I have now. The source prints great, but I still can't get the duration :/

Comment: `$("#video").load();` What are you doing here? The `.load()` method is used to load content via Ajax and inject it into the element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video - File Loading Complete Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138077/html5-video-file-loading-complete-event)

Answer (score 95):

You don't really need jQuery for this as there is a [Media API](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#media-elements) that provides you with all you need.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.src = 'my_video_' + value + '.ogg';
video.load();
```

The Media API also contains a [`load()`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-load) method which: "Causes the element to reset and start selecting and loading a new media resource from scratch."

(Ogg isn't the best format to use, as it's only supported by a limited number of browsers. I'd suggest using WebM and MP4 to cover all major browsers - you can use the [`canPlayType()`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype) function to decide on which one to play).

You can then wait for either the [`loadedmetadata`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-loadedmetadata) or [`loadeddata`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-loadeddata) (depending on what you want) events to fire:

```js
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    // Video is loaded and can be played
}, false);
```

Comment: I know, which is why I said to use MP4 AND WebM - WebM works on Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Thanks, your answer seems to have helped me but not exactly. I have edited the question

Comment: Ok, what gets printed out as the duration? Also you don't need the $('video') stuff, you can simply use: this.src for the source and this.duration for the duration, as this = v and v is a handle to the video. I think this is what's wrong as the jQuery $('#video') doesn't know what .duration is.

Comment: @IanDevlin what if I needed to dynamically add a video element to the page using JavaScript, when I drop a file onto the web page? At that point, I am using HTML drag and drop capability. I am able to do this with an image with the help of the FileReader API, once the reader finishes loading the file that was dropped.

Comment: The better way around these conflicting variables could be `$('#myVideo')[0].load()` because while the jQuery wrapper has a .load() function you can always access the underlying DOM elements directly with `[index]` syntax.

Comment: how to do it in typescript

Comment: @manishkumar here's a Typescript HTML5 audio wrapper https://gist.github.com/devfred/b34aafcb4402ac318ecaaa91f6816fc7 - That can easily be converted to wrap an HTML5 video API.

Answer (score 14):

In response to the final part of your question, which is still unanswered... When you write `$('#video').duration`, you're asking for the `duration` property of the jQuery collection object, which doesn't exist. The native DOM video element does have the duration. You can get that in a few ways.

Here's one:

```js
// get the native element directly
document.getElementById('video').duration
```

Here's another:

```js
// get it out of the jQuery object
$('#video').get(0).duration
```

And another:

```js
// use the event object
v.bind('loadeddata', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.duration);
});
```

Comment: For your second method, as Anthony mentioned above, you can also use this syntax: `$('#video')[0].duration`

Answer (score 2):

you can use preload="none" in the attribute of video tag so the video will be displayed only when user clicks on play button.

```html
<video preload="none">
```

Answer (score 0):

call function on load:

```html
<video onload="doWhatYouNeedTo()" src="demo.mp4" id="video">
```

get video duration

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var duration = video.duration;
```

Comment: This event isn't fired on video tags in latest Chrome (ubuntu, not sure if specific)