# html5 video wait for readystate == 4 after setting currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, readystate

I'm trying to grap some images of a video that is not played.
Therefore I use the HTML5 .

Because I want to grab images that haven't been played, I set

```
video.currentTime = y;
```

If I now call the grap function it won't work.
Because the `video.readyState` is 1 (and not 4).
If I add at the beginning of the grab function an `alert();` it works.

I tried to loop until `readyState == 4` with

```
while(true){
   if(video.readyState == 4){
       grapImage();
   }
}
```

but this ends up in an endless loop.

So how can I wait until `readyState == 4`?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864795/wait-until-an-html5-video-loads

Comment: My Problem is that, if I call video.load() I get the message "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." At the line where I call `video.currentTime = y;` with the method mentioned there as the second entry. Does load() destroyes the video element? Or why am I getting this Error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I solved it with the event listener `seeked`.

If you change the current time it changes to `seeking` once it's finished it goes to `seeked`. The `loadedmetadata` event is also an option, but `seeked` is the fastest one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html for relevent events to listen for.  Try listening to the 'loadedmetadata' event, rather than setting currentTime immediately after load(), as that indicates that all duration/timing information is loaded for a video ('canplay' also works).

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function () { console.log('video duration information available'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "canplay" for media. According to MDN web docs, media event "canplay" corresponds to the HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA readyState, which is readyState 4.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events