# Executing a function ? works only on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a div the same height of a video on my website.

so I executed this:

```
var videoHeight = 0;
videoHeight = $("video").css("height");
$(".tester").css("height", videoHeight);
```

in

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```

and in

```
$(window).resize(function(){}
```

but the height is only accurate when I resize the window, not on refresh. What should I do ?

when refreshing : the video is 554 pixels high and my div 493 pixels

when resizing : it is equal

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

Here is my video tag:

```
<video class="video"  preload="auto" loop="loop" controls>
      <source src="video/demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: @Baptiiste Amaud: can you upload any sample fiddle. Mean while you trigger re-size function in ready function also.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it'll work like this:

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    // Video is loaded and can be played

    var videoHeight = 0;
    videoHeight = $("video").css("height");
    $(".tester").css("height", videoHeight);
}, false);
```

[Wait until an HTML5 video loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864795/wait-until-an-html5-video-loads)

Comment: That's correct, the page may be loaded, but the video hasn't, so dimensions aren't available. The original code may work by luck of the video is cached. The only thing is that don't have to wait for the whole video to load, just its metadata, there's a metadata loaded event

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud make sure your `video` variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The video does not know its dimensions until metadata is loaded. Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata

```
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    var videoHeight = $("video").css("height");
    $(".tester").css("height", videoHeight);
}, false);
```

Note that the `loadedmetadata` event may already have fired by the time `DOMReady` fires so you may need to check the height before setting the handler.