# Play HTML5 video after its loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm searching for a way to play html5 video after its fully loaded. And while video is still loading - showing video placeholder image.
Before i've used setTimeout function, but its not the way to accomplish this.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('banner__video--fallback').fadeOut();
    $('.banner__video')[0].play();
}, 800);
```

So what is the way around this to play video after its loaded?

EDITED:
With solution 'canplaythrough' video still start ot be playing before its fully loaded.

```
$('.banner__video')[0].addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
  $('banner__video--fallback').fadeOut();
  $('.banner__video')[0].play();
}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until an HTML5 video loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864795/wait-until-an-html5-video-loads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use HTML5 video attributes? There's no need for javascript.

```
<video autoplay poster="/placeholder.jpg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

`autoplay` plays the video as soon as it is loaded and `poster` assigns an image to stand in the video while it's loading.

You should read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better option to play a video after its load:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    alert("Can play through video without stopping");
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can download video with ajax call like this:
[Another: Force Chrome to fully buffer mp4 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video/18294706#18294706) or just use `canplaythrough` property.

Comment: So im trying to go with canplaythrough, but its been playing before its fully loaded

    $('.banner__video')[0].addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
      $('banner__video--fallback').fadeOut();
      $('.banner__video')[0].play();
    }, false);

Comment: @MaryOleksiuk yes, because this event is trigger when enough data is loaded to play. Please try with ajax call (see the link).