# Vue firing mounted functions before video duration available

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get the duration of a video and place it in a div upon the Vue mounted() function firing. Code below:

Markup:

```
<video v-on:click="playPause()" id="tsGameFilm" ref="gameFilm" preload="metadata">
   <source src="#hiddenForSO#" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

mounted() function

```
mounted() {
  this.setTime();
  this.$refs.endOfVideo.innerHTML = this.prettifyTimestamp(this.$refs.gameFilm.duration);
},
```

The problem I am having is that "this.$refs.gameFilm.duration" is returning with NaN. My suspicion is that the mounted() function is firing before the duration is available for the video. This suspicion stems from the fact that the NaN loads before the first frame of the video does...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Attempted this to no avail:

```
mounted() {
  this.setTime();
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.$refs.endOfVideo.innerHTML = this.prettifyTimestamp(this.$refs.gameFilm.duration);
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps attaching event listener to wait for video load? See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875211/2411713

```
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
   // Video is loaded and can be played
}, false);
```

Comment: To make it work with Vue I had to do a v-on:loadeddata but this was the general solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted you might try to use `nextTick`:

`Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted:`

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and unfortunately it didn't change anything, still getting NaN. See the edit above to see if you agree with how I implemented...

Comment: Thanks for this though, I was able to learn the distinction!